# Customizing the add to cart function

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am new to WooCommerce and want to customize the functionality of add to cart. Can you please tell me where the function located along with the filename?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to use the woocommerce 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' hook to add your custom function. something like this :

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'my_function');
function my_function(){
    //........
}
```

This has been answered in another question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34255005/3134410

Comment: thank you... can you tell me where woocommerse defined this?

Comment: You're welcome.
This is defined here '/includes/class-wc-cart.php' but it's not recommended to modify woocommerce core as you can lose your changes in every update. Tha's why the best way to do it is to use a hook to add your custom function to 'woocommerce_add_to_cart'

Comment: I want to add to cart multiple products just like, /checkout/?add-to-cart=244&225 is this possible?